# Strange Behaviour with .errors on Factory Girl Stubbed Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I am using factory_girl_rails (4.2.1) and rspec-rails (2.14.0) to test a simple controller on Rails 4. When testing an error case, I use `FactoryGirl.build` to build an invalid `User` object. However, the resulting object does not contain any error in `@user.errors`; yet `expect(assigns(:user)).to have(1).errors_on(:email)` in the test case still passes. Why doesn't the FactoryGirl generated object has any error, and how does rspec see the error?

*Here are the details and code.*

The controller simply creates a User object, then redirect to a verification page if creation was successful or render the form again if there is any error.

```
class RegistrationController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.create(params.required(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation))

    if @user.errors.empty?
      redirect_to verify_registration_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end  
end
```

In my error case test, I create a `User` without 'email' using FactoryGirl. It is expected to create an error entry in `@user.errors` for the 'email' field AND renders the :new template.

```
describe RegistrationController do 

  #... Some other examples ...

  describe 'GET create' do
    def post_create(user_params)
      allow(User).to receive(:create).with(ActionController::Parameters.new({user: user_params})[:user]).and_return(FactoryGirl.build(:user, user_params))
      post :create, user: user_params
    end

    context 'without email' do
      before { post_create email: '', password: 'testing', password_confirmation: 'testing' }
      subject { assigns(:user) }

      it 'build the User with error' do
        expect(subject).to have(1).errors_on(:email)
      end

      it 'renders the registration form' do
        expect(response).to render_template('new')
      end
    end
  end
end
```

However, when I ran the test case, only the `'renders the registration form'` example failed, but not the other one.

```
Failures:

  1) RegistrationController GET create without email renders the registration form
     Failure/Error: expect(response).to render_template('new')
       expecting <"new"> but rendering with <[]>
     # ./spec/controllers/registration_controller_spec.rb:51:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.25726 seconds
6 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/registration_controller_spec.rb:50 # RegistrationController GET create without email renders the registration form
```

What is strange here is that rspec seems to be able to see an error in `@user` (hence the first test case passes) but for some unknown reason `@user.error.empty?` returns `true` in controller causing it to redirect instead of rendering the `:new` template (hence the failed second test case). I also confirmed in debugger that `@user.error` was indeed empty.

Is it something wrong with how FactoryGirl handles error, or am I using it wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things I want to mention here are:
1. Probably You want to use "Post create" instead of "Get create".
2. Whether email is missing or not is the model's concern, not controller's.
   I suggest you use stub to return false for the case that email is missing.

The easiest way is:

```
User.any_instance.stub(:create).and_return(false)
```

And maybe you want to change some other things in the controller, like "if @user.errors.empty?"

**EDIT: Sorry, "create" actually doesn't return false.**

So in your controller

```
@user = User.new(.....)

if @user.save
  ...
else
  render :new
```

And in your test use

```
User.any_instance.stub(:save).and_return(false)
```

Comment: Thanks. I was rather new to rspec testing and hadn't yet wrap my mine around the idea of isolating spec to simply test the flow of the controller. Now I got it.